# Ajax replace new arraylist without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new ajax, how can i replace ${phList} with new arraylist so that ajax can help me update the content without refresh whole page.

The ajax will trigger controller to retrieve data and store in arraylist then pass the arraylist to ajax. Ajax will update the content in jsp. Next step forEach loop will generate the column and checkbox with value if there have record retrieve from database.

Any solution and hope this solution can help others. Thanks!

**myJsp.jsp**

```
<select id="selected_year" name="selected_year" class="form-control">
    <c:forEach var="line" items="${yearlist}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${refreshInd ge 0 and line eq refreshInd}">
                <option selected="selected"><c:out value="${line}" />
                </option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option><c:out value="${line}" /></option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

    </c:forEach>
</select>

<c:forEach var="ph" items="${phList}" varStatus="PHstatus">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <form:input path="phList[${PHstatus.index}].holidayDesc" class="form-control col-md-5" value="${ph.holidayDesc}" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <form:input path="phList[${PHstatus.index}].startDate" class="form-control" value="${ph.startDate}" id="calendar1" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" onkeypress="return noAlphabet(event)" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <form:input path="phList[${PHstatus.index}].endDate" class="form-control" value="${ph.endDate}" id="calendar2" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" onkeypress="return noAlphabet(event)" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <form:checkbox path="phList[${PHstatus.index}].checkboxDel" value="" class="cbposition" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </c:forEach>
```

After i change selected_year to  trigger the ajax, it work well but :success function(response) cannot work. I want to remove the existing ${phList} and update with new arraylist by replace ${phList} show at above jsp.

**myJavascript.js**

```
$(function($) {
    $("#selected_year").change(function(){
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var $form = $(this);
        var action = $form.find('.send').val();

        var list[];
        var array[];

        $.ajax("holiday/pubholiday.json?" , {
            method: "GET",
            accepts: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serialize() + '&selectedText=' + selectedText,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#phList").remove()
                $(JSON.stringify(response))
    //how to pass the response which is my new arraylist to replace the ${phList}
              },
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            alert("Data Sent" + selectedText)
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = "";
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                errorMessage = "Your session has expired. Please <a href=\"<spring:url value='/login'/>\">login</a> again.";
            }else if(jqXHR.status == 500){
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
                   console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                   console.log(thrownError);
            }else {
                try {
                    var errorJson = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    errorMessage = errorJson.error;

                } catch (e) {
                errorMessage = errorThrown || textStatus;
            }
            }
            });
    })
});
```

This is object model store in the arraylist. Each record will contain object model data.

**model.java**

```
    public class PubHoliday {
    private int year;
    private String holidayID;
    private String holidayDesc;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private boolean checkboxDel;
    private String selected_year;
    private int refreshInd;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getHolidayID() {
        return holidayID;
    }
    public void setHolidayID(String holidayID) {
        this.holidayID = holidayID;
    }
    public String getHolidayDesc() {
        return holidayDesc;
    }
    public void setHolidayDesc(String holidayDesc) {
        this.holidayDesc = holidayDesc;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public boolean getCheckboxDel() {
        return checkboxDel;
    }
    public void setCheckboxDel(boolean checkboxDel) {
        this.checkboxDel = checkboxDel;
    }
    public String getSelected_year() {
        return selected_year;
    }
    public void setSelected_year(String selected_year) {
        this.selected_year = selected_year;
    }
    public int getRefreshInd() {
        return refreshInd;
    }
    public void setRefreshInd(int refreshInd) {
        this.refreshInd = refreshInd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about problem. You have provided quite a bit of code but no reference as to what works or doesn't and what needs changing

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to wrapper `<c:forEach var="ph" items="${phList}" varStatus="PHstatus">` by div with id, example:

```
<div id="list_holidays">
<c:forEach var="ph" items="${phList}" varStatus="PHstatus">
  .......
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Then in success ajax code
- Empty div#list_holidays
- Get result, each row, create new div, append to div#list_holidays

```
success: function(response) {
    var wrapper = $('#list_holidays');
    wrapper.html('');
    //->foreach response result
    //   -> $('div').html(your template).appendTo(wrapper)
}
```

Comment: It work half. After i try the wrapper, it overwrite my whole webpage and the template being loop is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is server side rendering. meaning, when a request is received server uses the variable `${phList}` to render a dynamic HTML page and sends that page to the browser. Ajax is a request made by your javascript sitting in browser. So, the browser has no way of knowing or changing the variable `$(phList}` directly and affecting the template.

However, what you said can be achieved. In one of following ways

**Method 1** *(easiest)*:

Implement `holiday/pubholiday.asp` which responds with only this instead of json.

```
<c:forEach var="ph" items="${phList}" varStatus="PHstatus">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form:input path="phList[${PHstatus.index}].holidayDesc" class="form-control col-md-5" value="${ph.holidayDesc}" />
    </div>
  ...
  <br>
</c:forEach>
```

Add a container element to the array items something like this

```
<div id="container" >
  <c:forEach var="ph" items="${phList}" varStatus="PHstatus">
    ...
  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Change your ajax request in main page to this. When you get a response from `pubholiday.jsp`, replace contents of `#container` to what is received from ajax.

```
...
$.ajax("holiday/pubholiday.asp?" , {
        method: "GET",
        accepts: "application/html",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $form.serialize() + '&selectedText=' + selectedText,
        success: function(response) {
            // This is where magic happens
            $("#container").html(response);   
        },
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        alert("Data Sent" + selectedText)
    })
...
```

**Method 2**:

If you need the response to be only json, in `success callback` read the json, and generate html yourself by concatenating strings and then replace the `#container` element.

**Method 3** *(recommended)*:

User some client side rendering library like polymer or handlebars to render json into html.

Comment: The old arraylist ${phList} still remain, cannot replace by my new arraylist.

Comment: which method did you follow. can you explain more about what you tried so i can help